# Find all possible values of $x$ if $\sqrt[7]{x+3}+\sqrt[7]{6-x}=\sqrt[7]{9}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all possible values of $x$ if $\sqrt[7]{x+3}+\sqrt[7]{6-x}=\sqrt[7]{9}$.

I did this problem by trial and error method. But I know that it isn't a mathematical way of solving a given problem. I would like to know other answers incorporating mathematical proofs for solving this problem.

Comment: Here, two solutions can be guessed. In general, solving this is very cumbersome and I would use numerical methods instead , if the guess would not work. It is not quite obvious whether there are more real solutions.

Comment: I am not even sure whether an exact solution (by radicals) is possible in general for this type of equations. The polynomial we finally get will have a quite high degree.

Comment: @Peter Here you go :) I believe there's also a easier solution by substituting $x = \frac{a}{\sqrt[7]{9}}$ and $y = -\frac{b}{\sqrt[7]{9}}$, since then it becomes $x - y = 1$ and $x^7 - y^7 = 1$.

Comment: "Find all possible values of $x$" where? in $\Bbb R$? in $\Bbb C$? in some finite field? ...

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't know my theory well enough, but for all the fields you mentioned, a degree $k$ polynomial has at most $k$ roots, so my answer found all of them (provided they exist, which they do in some extension field anyways)

Comment: @GarethMa Your answer [+1] assumes the field is $\Bbb C$
 (viewed at will as an extension of $\Bbb R,$ as was probably the OP's intention), but I agree it can be adapted to any field. P.S. Well, *nearly* any (see the final remark in my recently edited answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x + 3 = a^7$ and $6 - x = b^7$, then you want to find the intersection between $a + b = \sqrt[7]{9}$ and $a^7 + b^7 = 9$. Now, denote $t = \sqrt[7]{9}$ to simplify notation. Substituting $a = t - b$ and simplifying using the relation for $t$, you will get

$$
(7t)b^6-(21t^2)b^5+(35t^3)b^4-(35t^4)b^3+(21t^5)b^2-(7t^6)b+9=9
$$

Simplifying,

$$
b^6 - 3tb^5 + 5t^2b^4 - 35t^3b^3 + 21t^4b^2 - 7t^5b = 0
$$

We then note that $b = 0$ is a solution, and hence by symmetry of $(a, b) \mapsto (b, a)$, $b = t$ is also a solution. Factoring out the linear factors,

$$
b(b - t)(b^4 - 2tb^3 + 3t^2b^2 - 2t^3b + t^4) = 0
$$

Finally, note that the quartic has (alternating) coeffiicents $1, 2, 3, 2, 1$. This is well known to be the square of trinomial:

$$
b(b - t)(b^2 - tb + t^2)^2 = 0
$$

Therefore, the solutions to your problem are $b \in \{0, t, \frac{t \pm t\sqrt{3}i}{2}\} = \{0, t, t\zeta_6, t\overline{\zeta_6}\}$, where $\zeta_6 = \exp\left(\frac{1}{3}\pi i\right)$.

Finally, we recover $x$ by $x = 6 - b^7 \in \{6 - 0, 6 - 9, 6 - 9\zeta_6, 6 - 9\overline{\zeta_6}\}$.

Comment: @AnneBauval My bad, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

The $7$-th roots being ambiguous, let us reformulate the problem as: find $a,b$ (let us say in some field $\Bbb K,$ not necessarily $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, but at least of characteristic distinct from $7$ and $3$ - these two cases will be solved separately in the final remark) such that
$$(a+b)^7=9\quad\text{and}\quad a^7+b^7=9,$$
the corresponding solution being $x=a^7-3=6-b^7$.

Put aside the two trivial solutions
$$x=-3\quad\text{or}\quad x=6$$
(corresponding respectively to $a=0$ or $b=0$) and let $u=\frac ab.$ Then, the problem is equivalent to: $x=\frac{6u^7-3}{1+u^7}$ for some $u\notin\{0,-1\}$ such that
$$(u+1)^7=u^7+1.$$
Since $\left(X+1\right)^7-X^7-1=7X\left(X+1\right)\left(X^2+X+1\right)^2,$ this is equivalent to $u^2+u+1=0,$ i.e.
$$u^3=1\quad\text{but}\quad u\ne1.$$
Whence the only two non-trivial solutions, corresponding to these two values for $u$ (whenever they belong to $\Bbb K$):
$$x=\frac{6u-3}{-u^2}=6+9u.$$

Remark: let $S$ be the set of $7$-th powers of all the elements of $\Bbb K.$

1. If the characteristic of $\Bbb K$ is $3,$ the initial system of two equations boils down to $a+b=0$ and the solutions $x$ of the problem are the elements of $S.$
2. If the characteristic of $\Bbb K$ is $7,$ the equation $(u+1)^7=u^7+1$ is satisfied by every $u\in\Bbb K$ and the solutions $x$ are $6=-1$ and every element of the form $\frac{6s-3}{1+s}$ for some $s\in S\setminus\{-1\}.$